# Error Fix Xcode 10, Swift 4 initializer for conditional must have optional

Tags: xcode10, ios12, swift4.2

So I'm working on a savings app using a table view controller. I ran into an error, and I couldn't find a fix.

```
if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? SavingsTableViewController, let saving = sourceViewController.savings {
  let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: saving.count, section: 0)
  saving.append(saving)
  SavingsTableViewController.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

The error shows up as Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[Savings]'

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? SavingsTableViewController, let saving = sourceViewController.savings {
    let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: saving.count, section: 0)
    // and so on
```

To

```
if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? SavingsTableViewController {
    let saving = sourceViewController.savings
    let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: saving.count, section: 0)
    // and so on
```

(Your code still won’t work as intended, but this will get you past the compile error.)